# NSCocoaErrorDomain = 256

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm using this code to get the php page response from a GET call from my iOS app.

```
NSLog(@"%@", parameters);
// Send data to the web services
NSError *error;
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://178.63.103.3/hermes-resource/ws.php%@", parameters]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);
NSString *result_;
if (result)
{
    result_ = [self convert:result];
}
```

That's the error I got from stringWithContentsOfURL method and the log of parameters string.

```
2014-07-18 11:44:51.036 Hermes[542:60b] ?name=Luca D'Alberti&email=email@ext.it&range=21-39&graphic=5&userx=1&gamed=Si&comment_game=&errors=No&comment_errors=&feed=Fvdgd fvdgd
2014-07-18 11:44:51.042 Hermes[542:60b] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"
```

Why this error do occur?

Comment: *Please*, search, research and read documentations, tutorials, and previously asked questions before posting duplicate questions. Also questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Try breaking down the complicated `result = ` line. For example: what value do you get with the `URLWithString:`? (I bet it's nil.)

Comment: @Neeku Ok, I'm sorry.
I solved using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding method on parameters string

Answer (score 0):

The error is `NSFileReadUnknownError` source: [Foundation Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)